# Automorphism of a group G

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a group, and let $a$ be a fixed element of $G$. Define the function $\gamma_a(x)=axa^{-1}$ for all $x \in G$. Prove that $\gamma_a$ is an automorphism. For $G=S_3$, compute $\gamma_{(1 \ 2 \ 3)}$, that is, write $\gamma_{(1 \ 2 \ 3)}$ in table form.

---

Proving $\gamma_a$ is an automorphism:

For any $x,y \in G$,

$$\begin{align}
\gamma_a(xy) & =  axya^{-1}\\
& =axa^{-1}aya^{-1}\\
& =\gamma_a(x)\gamma_a(y)
\end{align}$$

Thus $\gamma_a$ is a homomorphism. Now for injectivity:

Let $\gamma_a(x)=\gamma_a(y)$. So $axa^{-1}=aya^{-1}.$ Right multiplying by $a$ and left multiplying by $a^{-1}$, $x=y$. Now take $y \in G$. Choose $x=a^{-1}ya$. Then $\gamma_a(x)=\gamma_a(a^{-1}ya)=aa^{-1}yaa^{-1}=y$. Since $\gamma_a$ is injective and a homomorphism, $\gamma_a$ is an automorphism.

---

Do I need to do anything more to show it's an automorphism, i.e., is it enough to show that $\gamma_a$ is an isomorphism?

---

And now how do I go about computing $\gamma_{(1 \ 2 \ 3)}$? What is meant by writing $\gamma_{(1 \ 2 \ 3)}$ in table form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof is perfectly OK. For the $\gamma_{(123)}$, just calculate its action on all the group elements of $S_3$, yielding a $ 1 \times 6$ table. These kind of automorphisms are called *inner*. You could make it into a $6 \times 6$ table if you want, where for all $\sigma \in S_3$ you calculate the images of $\gamma_{\sigma}$ on all group elements.